# Standard deviation depending on variable

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this in R (but much bigger):

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y<-c(2,5,3,4,9,63)
run<-c(1,1,2,2,1,1)
studie<-c("stu1","stu1","stu1","stu1","stu2","stu2")
df<-data.frame(x,y,run,studie)
```

I want to calculate the standard deviation for each column(in this case just x and y) for each run on each studie, sd for each studie and finally a sd for the whole column. A bit confusing explanation but in this case it would be a sd for (on x):

```
(1,2) since they both are in studie 1 and on run 1,
(3,4) since they both are in studie 1 and on run 2,
(5,6) since they both are in studie 2 and on run 1,
(1,2,3,4) since they are in studie 1 
(5,6) since they are in studie 2
(1,2,3,4,5,6) since they are in column 1.
```

I think I should use apply function but cant figure out how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you can use [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) and then [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html):

```
aggregate(cbind(x,y)~run+studie,df,sd);
##   run studie         x          y
## 1   1   stu1 0.7071068  2.1213203
## 2   2   stu1 0.7071068  0.7071068
## 3   1   stu2 0.7071068 38.1837662
aggregate(cbind(x,y)~studie,df,sd);
##   studie         x         y
## 1   stu1 1.2909944  1.290994
## 2   stu2 0.7071068 38.183766
sapply(df[c('x','y')],sd);
##         x         y
##  1.870829 23.963862
```

---

Also, just in case you want to parameterize the target columns (requires using the non-formula interface of `aggregate()`):

```
vars <- c('x','y');
aggregate(df[vars],df[c('run','studie')],sd);
##   run studie         x          y
## 1   1   stu1 0.7071068  2.1213203
## 2   2   stu1 0.7071068  0.7071068
## 3   1   stu2 0.7071068 38.1837662
aggregate(df[vars],df['studie'],sd);
##   studie         x         y
## 1   stu1 1.2909944  1.290994
## 2   stu2 0.7071068 38.183766
sapply(df[vars],sd);
##         x         y
##  1.870829 23.963862
```

Comment: Okey, this looks pretty good. I have 100 coloumns which i want to calculate the sd for, so i tried to use 
vars<-df[,1:100];
aggregate(vars~run.+studie,df,sd)
but got the error 
invalid type (list) for variable 'vars'

Comment: Two corrections: (1) `vars` must be assigned to the names/indexes of the columns, so use `vars <- 1:100;`, and (2) you must use the non-formula interface of `aggregrate()` if you want to parameterize the target columns using `vars`, so use `aggregate(df[vars],df[c('run','studie')],sd);`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Sd= sd(x)) , by = .(studie, run)]
```

and for both columns, use `lapply` after specifying the `.SDcols` as 'x' and 'y'.

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sd), by = .(studie, run), .SDcols = x:y]
```

Answer (score 0):

When grouping with respect to studie and run

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% group_by(studie,run) %>% summarise(Sd= sd(x))
```

When grouping with respect to studie

```
df %>% group_by(studie) %>% summarise(Sd= sd(x))
```

For all the column

```
sd(df$x)
```